# How to add simple GPIO defnition to a device tree (Yocto)?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gpio, device-tree, texas-instruments

I'm working with TI AM64XX and a base project that has limited definition of some GPIO of the board on the device tree. And I need more GPIOs than what it's defined in the DTS in order to use in my c/c++ code later and manipulate them as simple outputs. Based on the datasheet I've selected pins `gpio1_26`, `gpio1_25` and I don't know how to modify the device tree exactly, in order to implement these three GPIOs

```dts
&gpio1 { 
     status = "okay";
     pinctrl-names = "default";
     pinctrl-0 = <&main_gpio1_pins_default>;
     gpio-controller;
};

main_gpio1_pins_default: main-gpio1-pins-default {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C8, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /* gpio1_26 */
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C4, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /* gpio1_25 */
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C0, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /*gpio1_24 */
        >;
};
```

Have you any idea?

I've tried some definition like this but it fails in the compilation part, here is the error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIzXU.jpg)

> label or path gpio1 not found

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your CPU but in general it should be possible to extend the current block by additional GPIOs.

```
main_gpio1_pins_default: main-gpio1-pins-default {
pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C8, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /* gpio1_26 */
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C4, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /* gpio1_25 */
        AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C0, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) /*gpio1_24 */
        [PLACE MORE ENTRIES HERE]
        >;
        };
```

Look into the description of your CPU to find the PIN of the required GPIOs. There should be also a description to calculate the address. For other TI CPUs this can be done with an online tool.
Or there could be a mapping file which contains all available GPIO pins. Grep the code for it.

Comment: With such a rating you must be able to make your posts formatted in much better ways.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the compilation output, there's no definition for `gpio1` node. `&` symbol in the dts makes reference to a previously defined node, if it wasn't defined by default or if you didn't explicitly defined it, that reference makes no sense.

Reviewing the dts 'k3-am642-sk.dts' that you are using I see that there's a node in the line 130 called `main_pmx0`, that's the main pinmux mode node and there you should add your config.

Other option (actually the recommended one) is to make a `.dtsi` file and include it your main, but for the sole purpose of simplicity you can modify the original one.

Inside the main pinmux node you can define your pins:

```
&main_pmx0 {
    custom_pins: custom_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C8, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) 
                AM64X_IOPAD(0x01C4, PIN_OUTPUT, 7) 
            >;
};
```

In the example I just added 2 pins, feel free to add as much as you want.

Doing this you should be able to work with the gpios with `sys/class/gpio` or with gpio char dev driver (or tools like libgpiod)

NOTE: Make sure to do the proper research about pinmux mode (refer to the corresponding reference processor manual), there are some pins that can't be used as gpios. I just copied the pins directions and pinmuxmode you write in your question, assuming you already got that info.

NOTE 2: If you're compiling using bitbake then you should recompile .wic image, otherwise nvm

NOTE 3 (Answering to your comment):
If you don't see `/sys/class/gpio` that's because it's deprecated and the new standard is to use `gpio char device`. If you do `ls /dev` you will find some character dev drives called something like `gpiochipX`.
If you want to add sys/class/gpio then you have to configure it in the kernel menuconfig:

Open kernel menuconfig and activate the following:

```
Symbol: EXPERT [=y]
Location:
General Setup --->
    [*] Configure standard kernel features (expert users)

Symbol: SYSFS [=y]
Location:
File systems --->
    Pseudo file systems --->
        -*- sysfs file system support

Symbol: GPIO_SYSFS [=y]
Location:
Device Drivers --->
    [*] GPIO support --->
        [*] sys/class/gpio
```

Comment: Hello , first of all thank you for your answer , i ve done this , that resolved the error .. but the new problem is that i don"t have gpio in sys/class

Comment: I edited my answer, check note 3. If your main question was resolved consider marking it as accepted answer

Comment: @AnswerAndGetaCandy, and there is highly recommended **not** use deprecated sysfs interface for GPIOs.